# Who must I be? I'm blue as can be

Tags: riddle

> Sharing a name with a pear based beverage,
>
> No one suspects me of anything.
>
> Missing most of the time,
>
> Away to fight a German sounding guy.
>
> I work at Overly Worshiped Cat Apartment,
>
> Always home in time for the end of the episode.

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> Perry the Platypus, in [Phineas and Ferb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb).

Sharing a name with a pear based beverage,

> [Perry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry)

No one suspects me of anything.

> Well, no-one in Phineas's family.....

Missing most of the time,

Away to fight a German sounding guy.

> Dr. Heinz Doofenshmirtz.

I work at Overly Worshiped Cat Apartment,

> Actually O.W.C.A, which is, infact, Organisation without a cool acronym.

Always home in time for the end of the episode.

> Self-explanatory.

Comment: Nice job and complete Explanations!